# change how payment type shows on front end in magento 1.9

Tags: payment-methods

i have created some(6) **custom payment methods** but i don't  want them to show in a **select format**, i want them in a drop down form at frontend, i tried protected $_canUseCheckout = false; to hide it from front end and used

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on system -> payment/shipping method access -> payment methods.
**And you must select store scope on Current Scope necessarily.**

you can allocate payment methods to specific customer group/multiple groups